# Неправильная точка и скобка?

Tags: java

Что здесь может быть не так и как с этим бороться?[image: Неправильная точка и скобка?Как?]

Comment: Покажите что у вас за класс MainClass?

Comment: Пожалуйста, почитайте книги по синтаксису java, вопрос более чем базового уровня.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь методы класса вызывать посреди объявления другого класса. Это так не работает. Не ясно что находится в вашем классе MainClass, но тем не менее это, полагаю, должно выглядеть примерно так.

Ваш MainClass

```
class MainClass{
    String myLittleString;

    public String getMyLittleString() {
        return myLittleString;
    }

    public void setMyLittleString(String myLittleString) {
        this.myLittleString = myLittleString;
    }
}
```

Класс с функцией public static void main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass Nechto = new MainClass();
        Nechto.setMyLittleString("ЗАРАБОТАЛО");
    }
}
```